# Using log4j2 gelflayout, is there a way to suppress adding the underscore in the final payload

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, graylog, gelf

We are trying to set a custom field but the GelfLayout with log4j seems to inject an under score when using the Key Value configuration.  Is there a way to override that.

Here is the configuration:

```
 <Console name="GreyLogSysOut" target="SYSTEM_OUT">                
        <GelfLayout compressionType="OFF" includeStackTrace="true" includeThreadContext="true" >  
            <KeyValuePair key="host" value="$${ctx:mdchost}" />            
            <KeyValuePair key="level" value="3" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_timestamp" value="${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_timestamp" value="${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}" />                                        
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_environment" value="$${ctx:mdcenv}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_userid" value="$${ctx:mdcLogAgentId}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_process" value="PriPolApps" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_appclass" value="PriPolApps" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_appid" value="$${ctx:mdcappid}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_sessionId" value="$${ctx:mdcLogSessionId}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_correlationId" value="$${ctx:correlationId}" />                
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_logdir" value="${sys:appserver.Name}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_jvm" value="$${ctx:jvm}" />
        </GelfLayout>        
    </Console>
```

But the output injects underscore, is there a way to remove.

"_GL_correlationId":"${ctx:correlationId}",
"_GL_logdir":"/usr/local/pfs/logs/server6/",
"_GL_jvm":"${ctx:jvm}",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to remove this. The answer is quite straightforward.

Just use the `Custom GelfLayout`. You can use the configuration from above but remove the `includeStackTrace`, `includeThreadContext` and `customFields` line:

```
 <GelfLayout compressionType="OFF" includeStackTrace="true" includeThreadContext="true" >  
            <KeyValuePair key="host" value="$${ctx:mdchost}" />            
            <KeyValuePair key="level" value="3" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_timestamp" value="${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}" />                                            
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_environment" value="$${ctx:mdcenv}" />
            <KeyValuePair key="GL_userid" value="$${ctx:mdcLogAgentId}" />            
        </GelfLayout>
```

And you will have this output:

`"_GL_correlationId":"${ctx:correlationId}", "_GL_logdir":"/usr/local/pfs/logs/server6/", "_GL_jvm":"${ctx:jvm}",`

Comment: I am not following, I dont want the underscore to appear

Comment: That's not actually true.

There is a line in my answer that you are missing. It's a bit more complicated than that:

`<KeyValuePair key="GL_environment" value="$${ctx:mdcenv}" />`
This part is just to override the name of the environment (you have `mdcenv` defined but it is not included in the default layout). This string is included in any case by graylog.
Then you have this gelfLayout code with an includeStackTrace and `includeThreadContext` disabled:

Comment: `<GelfLayout compressionType="OFF" includeStackTrace="true" includeThreadContext="true" >  
<KeyValuePair key="host" value="$${ctx:mdchost}" />            
<KeyValuePair key="level" value="3" />
<KeyValuePair key="GL_timestamp" value="${date:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}" />                                            
<KeyValuePair key="GL_environment" value="$${ctx:mdcenv}" />
<KeyValuePair key="GL_userid" value="$${ctx:mdcLogAgentId}" />            
</GelfLayout>`

If you want I can update my original post with formatted code.